# How to capture all groups including optional groups of URL?

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

I need to capture groups of following URL's in URL-redirection (IIS, web.config):

```
https://www.example.org/tags/1/a
https://www.example.org/tags/1/a/100
https://www.example.org/tags/2/intchars-æøå 
https://www.example.org/tags/2/test/150
https://www.example.org/tags/3/c/200
```

I need to detect:

- tags
- group 1: number (1,2,3,...)
- group 2: text (e.g. a, intchars-æøå,test,c)
- group 3: optional number (100,150,200)

My Regex is `tags\/([0-9]+)\/(.*)\/?([0-9]+)?` but problem is that it merges group 2 and 3. I get result like:

- group 1: 1
- group 2: a/100

instead of:

- group 1: 1
- group 2: a
- group 3: 100

See test here: https://regex101.com/r/a1uiun/1

This is how far I have gotten in web.config:

```
<rule name="Tags" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^tags/([0-9]+)/(.*)$" />       
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/redir/tags/{R:1}/{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

https://www.example.org/tags/1/a is detected but the last group is still merged.

Comment: The period in (. *) group 2 also accepts / hence it does not define group 3. try changing it to a to z and 0 to 9 to test with first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
tags\/([0-9]+)\/(.*?)(?:\/([0-9]+))?$
```

**[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/zbvceU/1)**.

**Changes to your regex:**

- `(.*?)` Changed the quantifier in the second group to a lazy one so that it doesn't match everything that comes after it.
- `(?:\/([0-9]+))` Added the next slash and the numbers into a non-capturing group and made the whole thing optional.
- Added `$` at the end to make sure the lazy match continues to the end of the line if the third group doesn't exist.

Comment: This is perfect. I tried fiddling around with the lazy group but never got the results that I wanted. Thanks for quick answer :)